# How to view Opendaylight topology on external webgui

Tags: python, html, opendaylight

I'm exploring ODL and mininet and able to run both and populate the network nodes over ODL and I can view the topology via ODL default webgui.

I'm planning to create my own webgui and to start with simple topology view. I need advise and guideline on how I can achieve topology view on my own webgui. Plan to use python and html. Just a simple single page html and python script. Hopefully someone could lead me the way. Please assist.

Comment: You don't want to use any JavaScript library/framework for rendering the topology? How are you planning to output a diagram with Python and HTML? The information can be read from ODL with the REST API, but the rendering is the tricky part, and you will need to implement that yourself, if you don't want to use the default weg GUI from ODL.

Comment: The default ODL GUI has been deprecated and removed because no one stepped up to maintain it. If it provides value for you, please consider stepping up to support the upstream. That's how open source works. :)

Comment: If you do indeed want to implement your own webgui, then the ODL NorthBound REST APIs can be used for that. The details depend a lot on which sort of networking protocols we're talking about. If its BGP, PCEP, or BGP-LS, there is a pathman application provided by Cisco you could use, or model your solution on.

Answer (score 0):

If a web GUI for ODL would provide value for you, please consider working to contribute that upstream. The previous GUI (DLUX) has recently been deprecated because no one was supporting it, although it seems many people were using it.